# Upgrading from PostGIS 2.1: "Error: attempt to redefine parameter "postgis.backend"

Tags: postgresql, postgis

Upgrading from PostGIS 2.1: "Error: attempt to redefine parameter "postgis.backend"

I am trying to upgrade my PostGIS database on AWS RDS, but I am getting an error when running `ALTER EXTENSION postgis UPDATE`, as shown below:

```
my_db=> alter extension postgis update;
ERROR:  attempt to redefine parameter "postgis.backend"
```

And here is some additional information about my database:

```
my_db=> select distinct probin from pg_proc where probin like '%postgis%';
-[ RECORD 1 ]-----------------
probin | $libdir/rtpostgis-2.1
-[ RECORD 2 ]-----------------
probin | $libdir/postgis-2.1

my_db=> select version();
-[ RECORD 1 ]-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
version | PostgreSQL 9.5.9 on x86_64-pc-linux-gnu, compiled by gcc (GCC) 4.8.2 20140120 (Red Hat 4.8.2-16), 64-bit

my_db=> select postgis_full_version();
-[ RECORD 1 ]--------+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
postgis_full_version | POSTGIS="2.1.8 r13780" GEOS="3.5.1-CAPI-1.9.1 r4246" PROJ="Rel. 4.9.2, 08 September 2015" GDAL="GDAL 1.11.5, released 2016/07/01" LIBXML="2.9.1" LIBJSON="UNKNOWN" TOPOLOGY RASTER
```

The closest resource I could find to address this issue was here: http://postgis.17.x6.nabble.com/postgis-backend-and-legacy-functions-td5009743.html although that issue involved referencing multiple PostGIS versions. It seems that I am getting the same error, but my error may have a different cause, because I am only referencing `postgis-2.1` and `rtpostgis-2.1`, as shown above. Any suggestions would be appreciated.

**Update**
This seems to be an issue related to RDS, where after a minutes I saw that a patch is applied to RDS via the event logs. After the patch is applied, running the `alter extension postgis update` command successfully upgrade the PostGIS extension. Closing this question for now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This seems to be an issue related to RDS, where after a minutes I saw that a patch is applied to RDS via the event logs. After the patch is applied, running the `alter extension postgis update` command successfully upgrade the PostGIS extension. Closing this question for now.